# How do I get this code to update every 5 minutes?

Tags: gtk, vala

So, I have this code for monitoring some stats of my laptop and I just wanted it to live update but after days trying I'm kind of giving up, here's the part of the code I want to update, feel free to check my github repo for more info
https://github.com/Azure-Orit/Ideapad-Battery-Saver/blob/main/src/main.vala

```gtk
switcher = new Gtk.Switch ();

File conservation_mode = File.new_for_path ("/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode");
FileInputStream @fis0 = conservation_mode.read ();
DataInputStream dis0 = new DataInputStream (@fis0);        
string line;
while ((line = dis0.read_line ()) != null) {
    if (int.parse (line) == 1){
        switcher.set_active (true);
        }
}

File cycle_count = File.new_for_path ("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count");
FileInputStream @fis1 = cycle_count.read ();
DataInputStream dis1 = new DataInputStream (@fis1); 
string string_cycles = dis1.read_line ();
var charge_cycles_value = new Gtk.Label (string_cycles);
charge_cycles_value.set_xalign (0);

File capacity = File.new_for_path ("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity");
FileInputStream @fis2 = capacity.read ();
DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream (@fis2); 
string string_capacity = dis2.read_line ();
var capacity_value = new Gtk.Label (string_capacity);
capacity_value.set_xalign (0);

File status = File.new_for_path ("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status");
FileInputStream @fis3 = status.read ();
DataInputStream dis3 = new DataInputStream (@fis3); 
string string_status = dis3.read_line ();
var status_value = new Gtk.Label (string_status);
status_value.set_xalign (0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working so I'll leave it here to other people, I got it working by using ".set_label" like this

```
private Gtk.Label capacity_value
capacity_value = new Gtk.Label ("");
Timeout.add(50, () => {
        File capacity = File.new_for_path ("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity");
        FileInputStream @fis2 = capacity.read ();
        DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream (@fis2); 
        string string_capacity = dis2.read_line ();
        capacity_value.set_label (string_capacity);
        capacity_value.set_xalign (0);
        return true;
    });
```

50 would be 50 milliseconds